# Firebase Databaseui give Blank Result in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a problem receiving data from `Firebase`.
When i start Typing then `Firebase recyclerview adapater`. show me my result. Without start typing, firebase give me nothing.

```
    public static class ChoiceFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public ChoiceFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static ChoiceFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ChoiceFragment fragment = new ChoiceFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }



    FirebaseDatabase mDb;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    RecyclerView mList;
    View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice, container, false);
        references();


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Questions,QuestionHolder> adapter=
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Questions, QuestionHolder>(
                        Questions.class,
                        R.layout.custum_question,
                        QuestionHolder.class,
                        mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(QuestionHolder viewHolder, Questions model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.question.setText(model.getQuestion());
                        viewHolder.ans1.setText(model.getOption1());
                        viewHolder.ans2.setText(model.getOption2());
                        viewHolder.ans3.setText(model.getOption3());
                        viewHolder.ans4.setText(model.getOption4());

                        System.out.println("OKKKKKKK    :"+model);

                    }
                };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void references() {
        mDb=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Questions").child("MyQuestion");

        mList=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_choice_questionlist);
        mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

    }
    public static class QuestionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView question;
        RadioButton ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4;
        RadioGroup ansGroup;
        public QuestionHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            question=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_custum_question);
            ans1=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_one);
            ans2=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_two);
            ans3=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_three);
            ans4=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_four);
            ansGroup=(RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.custum_question_group);
            ansGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

                                                        switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                                                            case R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_one:
                                                                // Pirates are the best
                                                                break;
                                                            case R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_two:
                                                                // Ninjas rule
                                                                break;
                                                            case R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_three:
                                                                // Ninjas rule
                                                                break;
                                                            case R.id.radio_cusutm_ans_four:
                                                                // Ninjas rule
                                                                break;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no one will be able to help you unless you add at least some code.

Comment: i give code you, so please help about this

Comment: You don't get any results until you start typing?

Comment: Yes I don't get results until start typing